# Property Status cannot be empty error in s3 yaml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create an s3 bucket using IAC (using CloudFormation and YAML Script) when I tried to create the stack it gave me this error "Property Status cannot be empty" I am not sure what it means and where things are going wrong. This is my first YAML script.

```html
Resources:
 MyS3Profile:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      #AccelerateConfiguration: AccelerateConfiguration
      AccessControl: BucketOwnerFullControl
      BucketName: naa-jivitam
      #IntelligentTieringConfigurations: []
      #InventoryConfigurations: []
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - Transition: 
                StorageClass: GLACIER
                TransitionInDays: 25
      LoggingConfiguration: 
        DestinationBucketName: naa-jivitam
        LogFilePrefix: my-s3-logs/
      MetricsConfigurations: 
        - Id: MyMetricsConfiguration
          Prefix: MetricLogs/
      OwnershipControls: 
        Rules:
          - ObjectOwnership: BucketOwnerEnforced
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration: 
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
      VersioningConfiguration: 
        Status: Enabled
      WebsiteConfiguration: 
        IndexDocument: covidform/covid_form/templates/index.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under LifecycleConfiguration, add a Status parameter.

```
Resources:
 TestBucket:
 Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
 Properties:
   BucketName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-test"
   AccessControl: Private
   LifecycleConfiguration:
    Rules:
      Status: Enabled
```

Comment: I dont want it to be expired or deleted I want it t be transitioned to next stages

Comment: I updated the answer, it was just an example. You only need to add Status: Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is syntax error problem

According to Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-rule.html

Status is a required field

```
Status
If Enabled, the rule is currently being applied. If Disabled, the rule is not currently being applied.

Required: Yes

Type: String

Allowed values: Disabled | Enabled

Update requires: No interruption
```

It's always a good idea to check the syntax for cloudformation syntax.